# Excel VBA workbook.open loop stopped by Data Link Properties box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to combine 184 Excel workbooks (8 worksheets each) into one master workbook (with 8 worksheets) by copying the non-empty rows (except header rows) on worksheets of the 184 workbooks and pasting them onto corresponding worksheets of the master workbook.

I try to do this with a "for loop" and "workbook.open()", but the Data Link Properties dialog box pops up in the middle of the looping process (after it has opened the 170th workbook), stopping the automation.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828540/suppressing-the-data-link-properties-dialog-box-in-excel-using-vba) facing similar situation, but no good answer was given.  Would be grateful if anyone could enlighten me with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following qualifier to your workbooks.open statement:

`Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="yourfilehere.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False`

Comment: Tried but the Data Link Properties dialog box still pops up.  Closing the box will trigger "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications - Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

Before opening the files of a folder, list them.
If you find anything like thumbs.db, delete it from the list.
That should solve the problem.